# Can I save/restore my split-window layout in the Eclipse Java editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, mylyn

I like to use Eclipse's Java editor feature that allows the me to split the editor window into several panes so I can look at multiple files at once.

[image: Sample split window layout]

Often the layout of the splits is context dependent.  Ideally I'd like to be able to save the layout itself as well preserve which files were open.  IntelliJ IDEA supports [saving the complete context](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/switching-between-tasks.html) including split window layouts.

I am already familiar with and use the [Mylyn](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/) task context save/restore.  In fact, the Mylyn task restore actually destroys and clears the split-window arrangement upon task switch.  There's a five-year-old [Mylyn bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166644) for this defect.

It seems that the save perspective feature also doesn't save the pane layout.  Is there a way to do this with or without a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

General answer: probably it's possible.

Open editors and UI settings are kept in `<WS>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml` path, in great part. As you can see it's kept in a place independent of the installed plugins, so you can even restore the layout when there are no plugins responsible for opened editors (it happens to me often, as I share one workspace between many Eclipse configuration).

Skimming through the Eclipse sources, I see this file being accessed from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench`, in `restoreState()` (reading) and in `recordWorkbenchState()`+`saveMementoToFile()` (writing). So reproducing this functionality in a separate plugin and reading/writing to a different (profile) file should be enough for basic usage.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this in so much detail.  I didn't mean that I wanted to write a plugin, but +1 for the effort!  Maybe someone else will come across this and develop a plugin given the info.

Comment: No problem, it's always a good way to kill the time learning something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible without using some sort of plugin. I frequently work with multiple files and split them like you do, but as I understand how it works, the layout remains so long as there is a file in that pane.

When you open a new editor and "split" the editor area (drag the tab for the editor to an edge of the editor area), Eclipse opens the editor in a new "editor pane". You can do this a number of times, as you've shown in your picture.

I think the problem with your idea is when all the editors are closed, then try to open a new item, which editor pane should it open in? Currently, you have a split pane view with files already open and try to open a new file, it opens in the last pane that had focus.

It sounds like a really good idea and I would suggest making a [enhancement ticket on Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/%20enhancement%20ticket%20on%20Eclipse) to add this functionality.

Comment: There is already a problem report for it as [linked to in the question](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166644).  It's more than an enhancement request, as switching contexts destroys the split screen setup.  If you know of a plugin that does this, please post it in the answer.